# What are the benefits of Apache Kafka's native binary TCP protocol over it's restful API?

Tags: apache-kafka

As per Apache Kafka's documentation, Kafka uses binary TCP protocol in it's native API's communication but they have also provided URL based restful API for the languages which don't support Apache Kafka's native API. I was just wondering if there is any benefit of native binary TCP protocol (supported in native API) over restful URL based communication with broker node? And I was also thinking that will restful API still maintain `only once` property?

Edit:
The restful API guide is here: https://www.confluent.io/blog/a-comprehensive-open-source-rest-proxy-for-kafka which explains how to produce and consume Kafka's message over restful API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no REST API included in Apache Kafka for producing or consuming messages as with the native Kafka protocol client implemented in Java.

There is a REST APIs in Apache Kafka for configuring Kafka Connect.

There are a number of third party REST Proxy implementations (such as the Confluent Kafka REST Proxy) which allow pub/sub over a REST interface but these are separate open source projects outside of Apache Kafka.

If you mean to ask what are the advantages to use the native Kafka Java Producer/Consumer API rather than these third party REST/HTTP Proxy implementation then these are some reasons:

One benefit is greater parallelism. A Kafka client will typically open up TCP connections to multiple brokers in the cluster and send or fetch data in parallel across multiple partitions of the same topic.

Another benefit is better network utilization as HTTP headers can add a lot of size to otherwise small messages while Kafka’s wire protocol is a compact binary protocol.

Kafka clients handle load balancing, failover, and cluster expansion or contraction automatically while REST clients typically require a third party load balancer to achieve the same functionality.

Kafka client can send their own authentication credentials for access control and bandwidth throttling (quotas) while all REST clients look to the kafka cluster as one Kafka client and therefore have common ACL privileges.

Kafka client libraries buffer and batch messages together into smaller numbers of Kafka produce or fetch requests while HTTP can only batch data if the programmer thought to publish them as a single batch.

The native Kafka protocol supports more than just what the producer/consumer api exposes. There is also an Admin API for creating topics, and modifying topic configurations. These functions are not (yet) exposed through the most popular REST Proxy implementations.

Comment: If I'm not wrong there is an official implementation of Kafka's restful API here https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest. They have also official documentation for the same which explains how to produce and consume messages over official restful API here https://www.confluent.io/blog/a-comprehensive-open-source-rest-proxy-for-kafka/

Comment: I work for Confluent so I am very familiar with the REST Proxy API. That REST API is not part of Apache Kafka. It is an additional component that is part of Confluent Open Source which is a distribution that is a superset of Apache Kafka. When you say “official” and “Kafka” that means only the parts you can download from the Apache website and that are licensed by the Apache Software Foundation.

Comment: okay, thank you @Hans for your explanation. Actually, I would think confluent is the official org behind Kafka, that was my bad. Thanks again for clearing my doubts